# Dropdown shows Image and Name of users in CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown box that contains of users with images. Like this image: Credits: Kendo. i want to create this type of dropdown with css only and js if needed. Is this can be done without plugin? 
[image]

Here's my sample out from database and php:

```html
$link=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','user','pass');
mysqli_select_db($link,"db");
$Sunshine_Award=mysqli_query($link,"select * from Sunshine_Award");
echo "<select style="width:161px; height: 33px; border-radius: 5px;"/>";
while($Sunshine_Rows=mysqli_fetch_array($Sunshine_Award))
  {
   

   echo "<option>".$Sunshine_Rows['name']."</option>";
           

  }
 echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. Have a go at it yourself and then come back if you get stuck.

Comment: yes i have my sample output. i have here a dropdown that contains a lot of user from database but im really having a problem with this type of css code.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have?

Comment: i just posted what i needed because i really dont know how to do this one

Comment: i updated the post this is just my example how i created the dropdown in php and i want them to create css but it makes me harder to code i dont have idea how to do the design like shown above

Comment: Just so it's slightly easier for me, can you post the HTML code of your dropdown? (Press CTRL + U on your keyboard and copy the dropdown code)

Comment: if i  convert the php code to html with no database my html code will looks like this that will easier to do designing

<select style="width:161px; height: 33px; border-radius: 5px;"/>
<option>Select your nominee:</option>
 <option>User1</option>
 <option>User2</option>
 </select> i wonder how i am going to put image in this html that is compatible to any browser

Comment: Afraid you can't easily use CSS to style `<select>`. Have you tried using a list instead?

Comment: the reason why i used drop down is to show only the specific users for every dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
<style> 
#panel, #flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}

#panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">

<div id=users>user name</div><div id=users>user name</div></div>
</body>
```

use your server side program to insert user name & image inside the `#panel`

Comment: Hi thankyou. It works if i try to select one of the users it's not working maybe because this is a combo box

Comment: just add css with active to div element